# How to set link color using jquery.css()

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to set `a href` link color using [the jquery css properties](http://api.jquery.com/css#properties) ?

Basically i need to style simple model http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal_v12/
there is `containerCss` options where i need to pass that style:

> New in 1.2, you have the option to use external CSS or to pass in CSS
>   attributes for the modal overlay, container, and data elements as
>   options. The options are: `overlayCss`, `containerCss` and `dataCss` and
>   take a key/value object of properties. See the [jQuery CSS Docs for details.](http://api.jquery.com/css#properties)

Comment: Are you just looking to set the link color, or are you trying to set the pseudo-classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use the CSS definition for it:

```
$('a').css({
    color: '#ff0000'
});
```

Or, alternatively, using a shorter syntax:

```
$('a').css('color', '#ff0000');
```

**EDIT:** since you are using Simplemodal: you are only able to style the overlay, container and data wrapper elements in your modal using the syntax described on [this page](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal_v12/). If you want to style anything else, simply use CSS or create a jQuery selector based on the DOM node you want to style.

Comment: @Joper you should really clarify your question next time. These 'some more details' basically turn it into a whole new question.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is

```
$('a').css('color','red');
```

But I think the best way if we creates a  class for them , because it's possible, that he/she need to modify other parameters too. 
In this case the CSS things will be in the CSS ( and the color is that) , and Jquery using only a  class for them .

So :

```
$('a').addClass('className');
```

and in the CSS

```
.className
{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using CSS for that ?

```
a{
    color : red;
}
a:link{
    color : red;
}
a:visited{
    color : red;
}
a:hover{
    color : red;
}
```

Comment: Seeing the fact he is using jQuery, I assume he wants to change the color based on some form of interactive use that goes beyond hovering.

Comment: Not enougth context to know, but I just inform him that it can be done wuth CSS. ;)

Comment: I understand :) Still, it's probably more a comment than a direct answer to his question.